# Android: Listview with Multiple adapters

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to display the Android ListView as shown below using multiple `ArrayList<PatientAppointmentList>` and `ArrayList<TimeSlot>`. But am unable to achieve this structure. `ArrayList<PatientAppointmentList>` is been populated from database and `Array<TimeSlot>` is locally created ArrayList. How I can match the time in `ArrayList<PatientAppointmentList>` and time in `ArrayList<TimeSlots>` is the issue.

Please refer the image below for more details and help me.

By the way, the text Available is not from database. If there is no appointment for the particular slot, I want to display the slot as available programatically.

Thanks in Advance.[image]

Comment: yourAdapter = new Adapter(Activity actiivty,ArrayList<TimeSlot>,ArrayList<PatientAppointmentList>);

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar Please elaborate Naveen, I didn't get your answer.

Comment: have u know coustem adapter

Answer (score 1):

Use ArrayList HashMap to combine both list data.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
TimeSlot[] timeSlotList;
for (int i=0;i<timeSlotList.length;i++){
     HashMap<String,Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     row.put("slot_time",timeSlotList[i]);
     // try to get data from your database base on TimeSlot and check if data is not available for this time slot put available static string other wise add data which are came from database.
     ArrayList<PatientAppointmentList> appointmentList = getAppointmentFromDatabase(timeSlotList.get(i));
     if(appointmentList != null && appointmentList.size() > 0){
         row.put("appointment_status",getAppointmentFromDatabase(timeSlotList.get(i)));
     }else{
         row.put("appointment_status","Available");
     } 
     list.add(row);
}
```

Comment: Haresh Chhelana: What if both array are not of same size?

Comment: If both are not same then how can you distinct which time slot for which appointment ?

Comment: I edited my question. The status 'Available' is not from database.

Comment: The issue is patientAppointmentList has a time say 18/11/2014 11:30 to 18/11/2014 12:00, I want to match this 11:30 -12:00 in my timeSlots array list and display in the listview. Please forgive me if its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Object ArrayList Appointment that contains ArrayList PatientAppointmentList and ArrayList TimeSlot

Appointment structure:

```
public class Appointment {
    TimeSlot timeSlot;
    PatientAppointmentList patientAppointmentList;

    public Appointment(TimeSlot timeslot, AppointmentList appointmentList) {
        this.timeSlot = timeSlot;
        this.appointmentList = appointmentList;
    }
}
```

Add timeslots for eachPatientAppointmentList:

```
ArrayList<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < patientAppointmentList.size(); i++) {
    appointments.add(new Appointment(new TimeSlot, new PatientAppointmentList));
}
```

Comment: Kaspar What about if both the arrays are of not same size. I mean, I have 12 hour slots from 09:00 to 21:00, and in appointment arraylist I may have only one appointment per day.

Comment: You can add empty appointment and when you are displaying it to screen you can just show Available.